# Jenkins can't build apk "Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'."

Tags: java, android, jenkins, gradle, apk

I'm new to Jenkins. I want to build apk using Jenkins but it failed due to this error:

What went wrong:

> Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
>   Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:releaseCompileClasspath'.
>   Could not resolve project :library.
>        Required by:
>            project :app
>   Unable to find a matching configuration of project :library: None of the consumable configurations have attributes.

I'm always getting this error whenever I set/specify the task at Invoke Gradle on Build section.
[screenshot of Invoke Gradle fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyFBI.jpg)

When I empty that "Task" field, the build status will SUCCESS but there's no build file stored on my workspace.

***Fyi, I'm using:
Windows 10,
Gradle 4.1.,
JDK 8u152***

Thanks!

Update:
I just notice that this error (exactly same) also happens on my Android Studio.

@bongo
This is the contents of my root folder:
[contents of root folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RP7o8.jpg)

Comment: Could You post screen of your project root folder ?

Comment: @bongo I just post the picture